# Fine Tuning Bert on Medical Dataset

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I would like to use a language model such as Bert to get a feature vector for a certain text describing a medical condition.

As there are many words in the text unknown to most pre-trained models and tokenizers, I wonder which steps are required to achieve this task?

Using a pre-trained model seems beneficial to me since the dataset describing the medical conditions is quite small.

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [What should I have done before asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261598/6664872). Your question is too broad and lacks research effort. The huggingface documentation contains some [examples](https://huggingface.co/transformers/v1.1.0/examples.html#fine-tuning-bert-examples) which are helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this question is too general to be on Stack Overflow, but I'll try to give some helpful pointers.

1. Try to look for any existing `medical` pre-trained models.
2. Otherwise, fine-tune BERT/RoBERTa on your domain or whatever downstream task (classification/Question Answering) you're working on such that it captures the unknown medical terms in your corpus.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, here are two pre-trained medical models that are based on BERT.  In rough numbers, they give maybe a 4-5% bump in performance over BERT alone, depending on the task:

**[BioBERT](https://github.com/dmis-lab/biobert)** repository provides the code for fine-tuning BioBERT, a biomedical language representation model designed for biomedical text mining tasks such as biomedical named entity recognition, relation extraction, question answering, etc.

**[BlueBERT](https://github.com/ncbi-nlp/bluebert)** repository provides codes and models of BlueBERT, pre-trained on PubMed abstracts and clinical notes (MIMIC-III).